# Chef - Notify a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

Is it possible to notify another recipe from within the recipe? Something like the following?

```
execute 'somecommand' do
  command somecommand
  notifies :run_state "recipe[another_recipe]"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only notify resources, not full recipes. In addition, a recipe is only run at most once during a chef run. Even if you include it multiple times, it will only be run once.

That said, if you want to encapsulate multiple resources as a whole so that they can be notified, you should create a [lightweight resource (LWRP)](http://docs.getchef.com/lwrp.html) which from the outside can be considered to be a resource in its own.